# Not able keep time permanent once i send it into the fields in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, timefield

ok so im automating a a couple of fields in the image added. i have everything done but the start time and end time revert back to zero after i put them in.

here is my current code for automating this

`

```
def add_meeting_track(self):
    Waiter().wait_timer(3)
    self.driver.find_element(*SummitPage.add_meeting).click()
    Waiter().wait_timer(3)
    self.driver.find_element(*SummitPage.display_name).send_keys("Test01")
    self.driver.find_element(*SummitPage.zoom_webinar_id).send_keys("91516169900")
    s_time = self.driver.find_element(*SummitPage.evt_start_time)
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '09:40:00';", s_time)
    e_time = self.driver.find_element(*SummitPage.evt_end_time)
    self.driver.find_element(*SummitPage.stream_link).send_keys("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqk65aqfJBo")
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '13:00:00';", e_time)
    self.driver.find_element(*SummitPage.track_day).send_keys(1)
    self.driver.find_element(*SummitPage.track).send_keys(1)
```

`[image]

Comment: If you remove your line `self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '09:40:00';", s_time)` and you use `s_time.send_keys('09:40:00')` is working?

Comment: no, send_keys doesnt work normally, instead of replacing the field with the numbers I want, it adds on the numbers i want to the end of the 00:00:00, example it would look like this after i used send keys 00:00:00:13:00:00